# Simple Powershell mail attribute import

Tags: email, powershell, active-directory

I have a csv with samaccountname and mail attribute for all my users. I'm about to uninstall exchange since we moved over to google last summer. Google syncs with the mail attribute (through GADS).

If something goes awry and I lose mail attributes on the uninstall.. What would be the simplest way of importing those same AD mail attributes I already have saved, back to each account?

(the samaccountname/mail attribute do not always match)

Comment: You could use the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working, from start to finish, to export the data from AD:

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

```
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SAMAccountName, EmailAddress | select SAMAccountName, EmailAddress | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\users.csv"
```

To import back:

```
    $Users = Import-csv -Path C:\Scripts\users.csv
Foreach ($user in $Users) 
{
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -EmailAddress $user.EmailAddress
}
```

Comment: Thanks @whatever for the help

Answer (score 0):

should be quite simple, general idea:

```
$importfile import-csv <file>
foreach ($Entry in $importfile) {
    try {
    set-aduser -identity $entry.<nameofsamaccountnamecolumn> -emailaddress.<nameofemailaddresscolumn>
    }        
    catch {
        Write-Host "Someerror"
    }
}
```